# MySQL make full use of a join

Tags: mysql, left-join

Okay maybe what I am trying to do is not possible, but it does make sense.

I have 3 tables: `users`, `comments` and `comments_ratings`. In `comments_ratings cr` I hold the comment's id, the user's id and the vote they gave, for each comment they have voted on. What I'm trying to do now is figure out if a user had voted on each comment returned  by the query.

```
SELECT
    c.*,
    u.name as authorName,
    SUM(cr.vote) AS rating

FROM comments c 
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = c.author 
    LEFT JOIN comments_ratings cr ON c.id = cr.comment

WHERE c.id <= ? 
GROUP BY c.id 
ORDER BY c.id DESC
LIMIT ?,?
```

So this returns each comment as an individual row ( unbelievable ), but instead of adding another join to `cr` in order to determine whether the current user had already voted on each comment, can I somehow use the one I already have that's `SUM`-ing the votes?

In other words, can I get an additional column that's holding whether user x has voted on this particular comment ( the row ) or not, without adding a third join?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: `WHERE c.id <= ? ` where comment id is less than or equal to the provided id? That can't possibly be right.

Comment: @DigitalChris that's because I cache the last comment ID when the user requested the page and I use it as reference to display older comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. I would prefer to do another join with `comments_ratings on c.id AND u.id = user in question`, but it is possible to extract what you need to do a simple check with php or any other language you use to display the result. Use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get a string of all ids that have voted on a comment, and then `explode` it to an `array` for reference.

```
SELECT
    c.*,
    u.name as authorName,
    SUM(cr.vote) AS rating,
    GROUP_CONCAT(cr.user_id) AS user_ids

FROM comments c 
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = c.author 
    LEFT JOIN comments_ratings cr ON c.id = cr.comment 
WHERE c.id <= ? 
GROUP BY c.id 
ORDER BY c.id DESC
LIMIT ?,?
```

Comment: I really like this suggestion. I'm using php which has the reputation of a fairly fast language. Why would you prefer to go with another join? It's a tricky choice, doh!

Comment: No it's not that tricky ;) MySQL will fix it for you almost instantly while php is a bit slower. Even though above works, go for another join!

Comment: I'm concerned about MySQL doing a lot of work because if one day the amount of record gets at a high number I guess it's not going to be that instant. My main point of view is, if I'm cycling through this table once, why shouldn't I extract all the data I need instead of opening it again :/

Comment: But that is exactly why you should do it in MySQL! If you write good queries and add the right indexes, even millions of rows will be joined and sorted in a heart beat. What if you have a 1000 votes to check in PHP for each comment?

Comment: Okay, I'm convinced. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it! `:)`